# Creating an actionlistener from a method in another class

Tags: java, swing, awt, actionlistener

Hi well my code so far does something like this: Click a button, opens a combobox. I want to select an option on the ComboBox and depending on which option is picked i want to open another combobox using getSelectIndex().

Here are parts of my code which are relevant. I know I have to make the other comboboxes not visible or removed but at the moment I'm just trying to make a combobox appear. As you can see i have inserted the actionlistener for the button which works and opens the combobox.however when selecting a string in the combobox no event occurs. However when I run it, no comboboxes appear.

```
public class Work extends JFrame {
// variables for JPanel

  private JPanel buttonPanel;
  private JButton timeButton;

   public Work() 
 {
       setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 

      buttonPanel = new JPanel();
  buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
  buttonPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 500));
      add(buttonPanel,BorderLayout.WEST);
      timeButton = new JButton("Time"); 
  buttonPanel.add(timeButton);


  buttontime clickTime = new buttontime(); // event created when time button is clicked
  timeButton.addActionListener(clickTime);

    Time timeObject = new Time();
  timeObject.SelectTime();
  buttontime2 selectDest = new buttontime2();
  timeObject.getAirportBox().addActionListener(selectDest);



   }



       public class buttontime implements ActionListener { //creating actionlistener for clicking on timebutton to bring up a combobox
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent clickTime)  {
           Time timeObject = new Time();
           timeObject.SelectTime();
           add(timeObject.getTimePanel(),BorderLayout.EAST);
           timeObject.getTimePanel().setVisible(true); 
           timeObject.getTimePanel().revalidate() ;
           timeObject.getAirportBox().setVisible(true);


  }
  }





          public class buttontime2 implements ActionListener{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent selectDest) {
   Time timeObject = new Time();
  timeObject.SelectTime();


  if(timeObject.getAirportBox().getSelectedIndex() == 1) {



  timeObject.getEastMidBox().setVisible(true);

  }

  else if(timeObject.getAirportBox().getSelectedIndex() == 2) {

  timeObject.getBirmBox().setVisible(true);
 }
  else if(timeObject.getAirportBox().getSelectedIndex() == 3) {

  timeObject.getMancbox().setVisible(true);
  }
  else if(timeObject.getAirportBox().getSelectedIndex() == 4) { 
 timeObject.getHeathBox().setVisible(true);
  }   

   }
  }



public static void main (String args[]) {
events mainmenu = new events(); //object is created


mainmenu.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
mainmenu.setSize(800,500);
mainmenu.setVisible(true);
mainmenu.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
mainmenu.setTitle("Learning how to use GUI");
mainmenu.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
mainmenu.setResizable(false);

}
}
```

my other class TIME

```
          import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import javax.swing.*;

 class Time
{

  private JComboBox timeAirportbox;//comboboxes declared
  private JComboBox eastMidbox;
  private JComboBox mancBox;
  private JComboBox heathBox;
  private JComboBox birmBox;
  private String[] airport = {"","EM", "Bham", "Manc", "Heath"};//array of airports   declared
  private String[] destination = {"","NY", "Cali", "FlO", "MIAMI", "Tokyo"};//array      of    destinations declared
  private JPanel timePanel;

    public void SelectTime() {



 //combobox objects created

  timePanel = new JPanel();
  timePanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
  timePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));

  timeAirportbox = new JComboBox(airport);//array is inserted into the JComboBox
  timePanel.add(timeAirportbox);
  timeAirportbox.setVisible(false);


  eastMidbox  = new JComboBox(destination);
  timePanel.add(eastMidbox);
  eastMidbox.setVisible(false);

  mancBox = new JComboBox(destination);
  timePanel.add(mancBox);
  mancBox.setVisible(false);

  heathBox = new JComboBox(destination);
  timePanel.add(heathBox);
  heathBox.setVisible(false);

  birmBox = new JComboBox(destination);
  timePanel.add(birmBox);
  birmBox.setVisible(false);




}



    public JPanel getTimePanel() {
    return timePanel;
    }

    public JComboBox getAirportBox() {
    return timeAirportbox;      
    }

    public JComboBox getEastMidBox() {  
    return eastMidbox;
    }       

   public JComboBox getMancbox() {
    return mancBox;
    }

  public JComboBox getHeathBox() {
    return heathBox;
    }

  public JComboBox getBirmBox()  {
    return birmBox;
    }       





    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Time object that is built in Work constructor is not used:

```
  Time timeObject = new Time();
  timeObject.SelectTime();
  buttontime2 selectDest = new buttontime2();
  timeObject.getAirportBox().addActionListener(selectDest);
```

As you are only applying the action listener `selectedDest` to the combobox of that timeObject, which is not used, then the listener will never be called.

You can do two things to make it work:

- Move the code that creates the listener and assign it to the combox in the first listener `buttontime`
- Create the Time object only once and store it as a member of your Work instance. As your listener is a non-static inner classes of the Work class, it will be able to use it instead of creating a new Time object.

**Edit:** I didn't see that in your second listener, you were AGAIN building a new Time object. This object is really a different one than the one you have created earlier, so modifying one will not affect the other. You really should create the Time object once and store it as a member variable of your Work class, and then use this object in your listeners instead of recreating it.

To be clear, do it like this:

```
public class Work extends JFrame {

    // ...

    private Time timeObject;

    public Work() {

        // ...

        timeObject = new Time();
        timeObject.SelectTime();
        buttontime2 selectDest = new buttontime2();
        timeObject.getAirportBox().addActionListener(selectDest);

    }

    public class buttontime implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent clickTime)  {
            // use timeObject, don't create it and don't call SelectTime()
            // example:
            add(timeObject.getTimePanel(),BorderLayout.EAST);
            // ....
        }
    }

    public class buttontime2 implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent clickTime)  {
            // use timeObject, don't create it and don't call SelectTime()

        }
    }
}
```

Also to note:

- You should not extends JFrame, there is no reason to do so. Refactor your code so that your frame is just a member variable of your Work class.
- Follow [Java standard code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html), especially use case properly with class names: `buttonlistener` should be `ButtonListener`, and method should start with lowercase: `SelectTime` should be `selectTime`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply im going to see if i can do this. Im confused about the Object concept though and how i can store this as a member variable

Comment: Thanks alot you've widened my understanding